# Non-root User Rsync Daemon rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1675) [Receiver=3.1.3]

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, rsync

I am on on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop and I am backing up a remote client Ubuntu 20.04 server using the following basic framework:

In `/etc/sudoers`
`non-root-username ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync`

From Desktop terminal I execute:
`rsync -a -e "ssh -i /path/to/id_rsa" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" non-root-username@xx.xx.xx.xx::data /local/path`

On remote client server, I have this in `/etc/rsyncd.conf`:

```
root@admin:~# cat /etc/rsyncd.conf 
# Global configuration of the rsync service
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
hosts allow = 123.123.123.123
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
# Username and group for working with backups
uid = non-root-username
gid = non-root-username
# Don't allow to modify the source files
read only = yes
# Data source information
[data]
use chroot = false
strict modes = false
path = /backups
list = yes
auth users = non-root-username
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.passwd
```

In my `/etc/rsyncd.passwd` file, I have:

```
root@admin:~# cat /etc/rsyncd.passwd 
non-root-username:password
```

I have these permissions for `/etc/rsyncd.conf`:

```
root@admin:~# stat /etc/rsyncd.conf 
  File: /etc/rsyncd.conf
  Size: 471         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 144028      Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1001/non-root-username)
Access: 2022-05-21 13:38:46.797769245 +0800
Modify: 2022-05-21 13:38:42.641735637 +0800
Change: 2022-05-21 13:55:52.384894170 +0800
```

And, I have these permissions for `/etc/rsyncd.passwd

```
root@admin:~# stat /etc/rsyncd.passwd 
  File: /etc/rsyncd.passwd
  Size: 31          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 144040      Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1001/non-root-username)
Access: 2022-05-21 13:38:06.989448597 +0800
Modify: 2022-05-21 13:37:37.473212811 +0800
Change: 2022-05-21 13:37:37.473212811 +0800
```

But no matter what combination if UID / GID  & permissions that I try, I always get the same error:

```
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS  <-- showing that it successfully connects, but doesn't authenticate
@ERROR: access denied to data from UNKNOWN (0.0.0.0)
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1675) [Receiver=3.1.3]
```

I have read the rysnc man pages and tried their troubleshooting suggestions... I don't see what I am missing...

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you really want to make use of the rsync *daemon* (which does NOT work over SSH so the transfer will be unencrypted unless it is done over some kind of VPN), it has to be already running on the remote machine and the command would be `rsync -a non-root-username@xx.xx.xx.xx::/data/ /local/path` (note the TWO colons, and `data`, which is from `[data]` in the `rsyncd.conf`). In this case I think you have to fix the permission of /backup and its children since I doubt that `--rsync-path=` is relevant. (No idea if you can start rsyncd as `non-root-username`.)

Comment: As for the non-daemon-involving approach in question, does `ssh -i /path/to/id_rsa non-root-username@xx.xx.xx.xx sudo rsync -V` work at least? Is there anything quirky in the actual full path (which has been *redacted*) of `id_rsa`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... I cracked it.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong. Apparently there's a third mode that allows you to spawn some kind of transient rsync daemon from the client-side when you have `-e 'ssh [...]'`  specified and `::` / `rsync://` in your rsync command. It's unclear whether `rsyncd.conf` in `/etc/` matters in that mode though (the manual only says that `rsyncd.conf` in `$HOME` will be used). (Regardless, it's still NOT what you were using, unless you missed a colon in command you typed above, and I doubt that any `rsyncd.conf` matters when you are not relying on a daemon-mode rsync, although I cannot rule out bugs.)

Comment: My apologies... I did miss a `:`  in the example above.. I was using `username@ip-addr::data`  I will go through and edit

Comment: @TomYan  2 perculiar things about my solution 1.) my hosts allow configuration is absolutely correct  & previously worked on a different server.  and 2. I check the remote clients rsync.log and I see `2022/05/21 17:34:58 [2463] connect from UNKNOWN (0.0.0.0)
2022/05/21 17:34:58 [2463] rsync allowed access on module data from UNKNOWN (0.0.0.0)`  even though everything is working, doesn't seem to authenticate the host.

Answer (score 0):

I went back to basics and figured it out.  The core problem was that `hosts allow = 123.123.123.123`  was blocking my own ip  (yes, I double and triple checked that the ip address was correct, the function just seems broken)

My final solution to the above is:

```
root@admin:~# cat /etc/rsyncd.conf 
# Global configuration of the rsync service
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
#hosts allow = 123.123.123.123  <-- hashed out
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
# Username and group for working with backups
uid = root
gid = root
# Don't allow to modify the source files
read only = yes
# Data source information
[data]
use chroot = false
#strict modes = false <-- (defaults to true)
path = /backups
list = yes
auth users = non-root-username
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.passwd
```

In my /etc/rsyncd.passwd file, I have:

```
root@admin:~# cat /etc/rsyncd.passwd 
non-root-username:password
```

I have these permissions for /etc/rsyncd.conf:

```
root@admin:~# stat /etc/rsyncd.conf 
  File: /etc/rsyncd.conf
  Size: 471         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 144028      Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1001/root)
Access: 2022-05-21 13:38:46.797769245 +0800
Modify: 2022-05-21 13:38:42.641735637 +0800
Change: 2022-05-21 13:55:52.384894170 +0800
```

And, I have these permissions for `/etc/rsyncd.passwd`

```
root@admin:~# stat /etc/rsyncd.passwd 
  File: /etc/rsyncd.passwd
  Size: 31          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 144040      Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1001/root)
Access: 2022-05-21 13:38:06.989448597 +0800
Modify: 2022-05-21 13:37:37.473212811 +0800
Change: 2022-05-21 13:37:37.473212811 +0800
```

Final command to back from local backup server:
`rsync -a -e "ssh -i /path/to/id_rsa" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" non-root-username@xx.xx.xx.xx::data /local/path`

Comment: I think I've successfully reproduced the problem. Apparently the problem only occurs when you use `-e ssh [...]` and `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"`. The truth is I don't think rsync expects you to do that anyway. Theoretically speaking the transient daemon started with sudo should use `/root/rsyncd.conf` instead of `/etc/rsyncd.conf` but in reality rsync becomes confused that the started daemon isn't a transient/user one and, maybe because of that, fails to "retrieve" the real source address.

Comment: Therefore I suppose what you are doing isn't exactly supported, and I think the "right way" to do it is have "proper" ownership/permission in `/backup` so that `non-root-username` can work on it as needed without requiring `sudo`, or use a "system" rsync daemon properly (`::` without `-e`) with some external approach (VPN, ssh tunnel, etc.) for encryption. (Or not using the daemon approach at all, if feasible)

Comment: Something seems off about this version of rsync 1.) the `hosts allow` option that I mentioned, simply doesn't work and 2.) without using the `-e` option rysnc doesn't read the ssh config and fails to connect, although `#ssh non-root-username@ip-addr` connects perfectly fine (reads config file) basically with your suggestion, I have to fiddle with the ACL to grant a non-root-user direct permissions to a system directory, which exactly what I am trying to avoid, hence I gave `non-root-username` passwordless access to rsync... :-/

Comment: Okay here's why `0.0.0.0`: https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/blob/v3.2.4/clientname.c#L63 -- at least on the server host in concern, `sudo` is not preserving any of the necessary env vars you can see in the code (in *my* case only `SSH_CLIENT` and `SSH_CONNECTION` are there), so you can use something like `--rsync-path='sudo env "SSH_CONNECTION=${SSH_CONNECTION}" rsync'` (note the *different* quotings). (`sudo -E` would work too but it will preserve other envs too which might cause other unexpected problem.)

Comment: The thing is using `::` together with `-e` is quite different from using `:` *(with or without `-e`)* and `::` without `-e`. The real question here is: do you really need/want to use a (transient) rsync daemon? Or do you really just need `sudo rsync` with `:` (daemonless approach)? Not experiencing any ssh config (or do you mean key) problem myself with 3.2.4 btw. (Well actually, never had)

Comment: I have been operating under the assumption that I need  to use the daemon in order to use sshd_config `Match User` / `ForceCommand` / `rsync`[..]  If can still use ForceCommand with `:`, then ditching the daemon approach seems to eliminate headaches...

Comment: `command="rsync --server --daemon .",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa` is in my authorized_keys.. I am editing sshd_config now

Comment: I fail to see how the rsync daemon can be relevant to `sshd_config`. The only reasons to use a daemon are that you need/want to use certain *rsync* feature that is available only when it's running in daemon mode (e.g. "modules"), or that you do NOT want to involve ssh at all (which would be invalidated when you use `-e`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136477/discussion-between-mjones-and-tom-yan).